# Listening to pageloads in new tabs

Tags: javascript, https, firefox-addon

my Firefox extension is listening to onSecurityChange events (page loads over HTTPS). For that reason I implemented a nsIWebProgressListener and registered it with getBrowser().addTabsProgressListener().

Inside the event handler I have to do some stuff, including suspending and resuming the actual nsIRequest. Most of the code inside the event handler is wrapped in an if-statement, checking if aRequest.isPending() is true (otherwise, suspend wouldn't work).

In general, that works well. But when I open a link in a new tab, onSecurityChange isn't called until the pageload finished (i.e. isPending is false). And this is too late.

What do I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

You got 3 options.

1. Continue with nsiWebProgressListener, add an onStateChange: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIWebProgressListener#onStateChange%28%29
2. Add event listner to browser to listen to page loads: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9287185#
3. Use channel observer to watch all channels and get the tab that called it and attach there (this one is trickiest because you'll have to use methods to differntiate between redirects and multiple channel executions some that you may not be able to get a loadContext from to get the tab for)

Comment: I would prefer the first option, since it seems to be the easiest. But is it possible to get the SSL validation result from Firefox/NSS inside onStateChange? Inside onSecurityChange there is aState object which lets me retrieve this information.

Comment: I'm not sure you'll have to play around with it. Share what you learn we're learning here too

Comment: it seems onStateChange is useless. when I type in `google.de`, there are two onStateChange events occurring. One STATE_START with request.name = `http://www.google.de` (w/o HTTPS) and one STATE_STOP with request.name = `https://www.google.de` (with HTTPS). STOP is too late and START is not fired for HTTPS when redirected from a HTTP page, so I can't do anything with the certificate. ..... isn't there a simple way to do something whenever a HTTPS page is loaded?

Comment: i would honestly go with adding DOMContentLoaded to gBrowser and then if its https do something else do nothing see my gists at github specifcially this one: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9406437

Comment: Don't know if DOMContentLoaded is too late. But I was able to do it with onLocationChange. Needs a lot of ifs and workarounds but works now. thanks.

Comment: Can you please share your onLocationChange function Im interested. Theres some good research on onLocationChange here: https://forums.mozilla.org/addons/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=16047

Comment: ok, I will answer my question and show something about onLocationChange. It may be not perfect yet, especially concerning the points mentioned in the thread you referred to.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to develop a (maybe hacky) solution which lets me intercept HTTPS page loads, using onLocationChange. This may not be perfect yet.

It was not possible to use onSecurityChange (as I described in my question) because the event was not fired properly when a link was opened in a new tab.

```
onLocationChange: function(aBrowser, aWebProgress, aRequest, aLocation, aFlags) {

    if(aRequest != null) {

        // suspend early, because that becomes impossible later
        aRequest.suspend();

        // check if it is HTTPS (no HTTP, no about:, etc.)
        if(aLocation.scheme == "https") {

            var whateverIWantToDo = {
                notify: function(timer) {

                    try {
                        // for example I'm interested in the validation result:
                        let secUI = aBrowser.securityUI;
                        secUI.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsISSLStatusProvider);
                        let status = secUI.SSLStatus;

                        // do something what you want here
                        // and do not forget to resume the request at any point. otherwise that could lead to problems
                        aRequest.resume();
                        //....
                        // the reason I suspend the request at all:
                        // I do not want to completely load the page until I know if the certificate is valid
                    }
                    catch(err) {
                        // maybe it's too early to access the SSLStatus when the event handler kicks in.
                        // in this case an error will be thrown which is caught here
                        // wait 10 ms and try it again, usually that works! (I know, it's a bit hacky)
                        var timer = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/timer;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsITimer);
                        timer.initWithCallback(whateverIWantToDo, 10, Components.interfaces.nsITimer.TYPE_ONE_SHOT);
                    }

                }
            }

            whateverIWantToDo.notify();

        } else {
            // continue normally when it's not a HTTPS request, we want to intercept
            aRequest.resume();
        }
    }
}
```